HVAC Keeps tripping breaker. Noticed my breaker is less than then Max on the side label - should I change?
tl;dr - Found that the breaker used for my AC is less than the max specified on the side of the unit. Any reason to keep the lower rated breaker or should I replace so it matches? Safety concerns or other? Do I need to check the wires or anything else?
Would adding a hard start kit have any impact either way in regards to this breaker issue?

Details / Questions:
I have had a few people out trying to diagnose my AC problem originally reported in a previous post. The best I got was "capacitor may be going bad"; no one will check anything directly on my fan or compressor... I changed the capacitor with a new OEM of the same make. Now the system is tripping the breaker only after a few minutes.
I was going down the path of adding a hard start kit, when I came across a post talking about checking for a breaker mismatch. I had considered maybe there was a breaker issue, but this was the first time that I learned that the required breaker should be printed right on the label.

Look on the side on the outside unit and find the nameplate sticker.
Look for a "Max Fuse/Breaker" size. It should say something like 40
Amps. Go check the breaker that's tripping and make sure it matches
that rating.

My label (photo below) shows max breaker of 50, but what I have installed is only a 40. I also checked my other AC unit's label which says max of 40, but in the breaker it is a 30.
My understanding is the label says the maximum, anything above that means you will have problems where the system won't break when it really needs to. However, I would wonder if there is a reason why the electrician or HVAC people who put everything in would go with a smaller breaker then the max? I am in a townhouse unit (only 5 years old new construction) of mixed sizes where mine is one of the bigger units, maybe they just installed the same breakers for each house based on the smaller units which have smaller ACs? In my research (see bottom of post) I see something about wire size that maybe impacts this?
If the label on the side of the AC unit says 50, would upgrading what is in my breaker to a 50 be a good idea? Any trade offs/risks why I would actually want the smaller one then it there? Also, this is the original AC unit and there were no problems for the first four years - was I just lucky and this was going to happen eventually OR is a 40 amp breaker not likely the problem?
I don't know how many more techs I can handle telling me nothing looks wrong....
Photo of the label on the unit which keeps tripping:

Photo from my breaker where the circuit breakers are for both ACs:

Photo of the label on the other unit which hasn't given me any problems:

Research:
Sizing wire and circuit breaker for air conditioner

So why is there a max breaker size of 45 amps when a 30 amp breaker is sufficient?

Yes, but it is possible that as the unit wears starting currents could creep up causing >> the 30 amp OCPD to trip. I would just use the max of 45 amps.


^^ not exactly sure what "unit wears starting currents" means, sounds like it may be what is happening to me?

The overload protection in the a/c protects the wire the breakers is there for ground fault and short circuit protection

Sizing an air conditioner circuit breaker
This one seems to be talking about wires and breakers; they seem more conerend with it being too high:

The most common defect that we find is an oversized circuit breaker. This typically happens because an air conditioner is replaced with a more efficient unit, but the circuit breaker in the panel is not replaced with a smaller one. If the electrical disconnect at the exterior has fuses that are sized appropriately, however, then it would be acceptable to have a circuit breaker that is oversized.


For air conditioners and heat pumps, we size the wires and circuit breakers in accordance with the information printed on the label, not the simplified sizing charts that we typically rely on.

A comment that may be relevant:

In new construction, the electrician arrives first and installs the circuit breakers before the HVAC installation company installs the AC or heat pump units. Evidence shows that they “guesstimate” what size breakers may be needed without consulting with the HVAC company. They will often put two of the same ampacity breakers in the panel. For example, they might install (2) – 30 Amp circuit breakers when one AC unit has a 20 Amp maximum rating and the other unit has a 30 Amp maximum rating.

AC UNIT Breaker size

However, just to be clear, you can't change out the breaker to match the unit if the wire sizes are still too small. Since it says to use a 20A, the wires should be 12 gauge or larger. Any smaller and they could burn up before the breaker would trip.

Though there seem to be some other comments to this answer and maybe it doesn't matter given the 2nd quote from the previous item? Maybe they went with 40 due to wire size? Can a 40 and 50 use the same type of wire? What do I check on the wire, can I check without removing the panel?
NEC question on AC circuit breaker sizing

CA determines the smallest conductor, disconnect, etc. size, to support continuous running current.
MOC determines the largest breaker or fuse (if specified) size, to allow for momentary starting current.
The breaker does not act as overload protection, which is built into the unit, only short-circuit protection.

HVAC guy says i can use 40 amp breaker on 50 amp AC unit.

Wire gets sized at or above the minimum circuit ampacity. Breaker gets sized above MCA but less than or equal to the max overcurrent device. It is not a firm requirement that it match the MOP exactly.
..
Your actual overload protection is at the motor, be it via a thermally protected motor, a motor starter with overloads, or a VFD. The breaker just needs to trip in a fault to keep the wire from burning up which is why it is allowed to be larger than the wire ampacity dictated by 310.16.

https://www.totalhomesupply.com/wires-and-circuit-breakers
This page would seem to indicate that for 40amp you need 8 gauge and 50amp you need 6 guage. But from the above maybe they were saying it was different for AC systems? Would I need an electrician to repull the line to switch to 50amp?

The unit that is tripping has:

Minimum Circuit Amps: 29.0
Max. Breaker: 50
Existing Breaker: 40

As a general rule, the minimum breaker size for HVAC is the equipment requirement (29.0) plus 25% for continuous usage. 29.0 x 1.25 = 36.25, which rounds up to 40A. Which means a 40A breaker is OK.
Similarly, the smaller unit has:

Minimum Circuit Amps: 23.5
Max. Breaker: 40
Existing Breaker: 30

Guess what? 23.5 x 15 = 29.375. That is, conveniently, and likely by design, close to 30A.
So while 50A and 40A are the maximum allowed, 40A and 30A are perfectly fine. Upsizing the breakers should not be necessary and in any case can NOT be done unless you verify the wires are sized accordingly. It is unlikely, but not impossible, that the wires are oversized (which is perfectly fine) for the existing breakers such that you can increase the breakers without replacing the wires.
As far as fixing the actual problem, that will depend on what is causing the problem. If the problem is when the system is starting then a hard start kit may be the solution. If the problem is after the system has been running for a while then something else may be going wrong. Diagnosis will require more information. Also keep in mind that a breaker can trip quickly due to a large overcurrent (e.g., 80A on a 40A circuit) or after several minutes for a small overcurrent (e.g., 50A on a 40A circuit), and the causes can vary quite a bit. In addition, if you actually have something like 50A on a 40A circuit, causing a slow but eventual breaker trip, moving to a 50A breaker will actually be dangerous because the breaker might never trip despite drawing far more power than it is supposed to draw.

Since the wiring came up in another question I asked, I took photos and opened a different question here showing my actual wires: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/300746/18714 Given my actual wiring, would it be okay to use a larger breaker or would this still be dangerous ; the compressor is being replaced under warranty in the next few days. So if I was having the short but large overcurrent or prolong small over current would this help or make things worse in the future?
